# To replace the whitespaces of string given string in c

Tags: c, string, programming-languages

I want to replace the whitespaces with string "IIT".I tried using loop in my string and when I encountered whitespace I tried to replace it with the given string. But the whitespace is similar to a single character in string so it is not replacing with a word so please help me out how can I replace my withspace with given word.Thank you .

Comment: create a new string and put your replaced content. simple

Comment: Agree w/Josh.  you cannot do this in-place.  Simplest solution would be to scan through once to count whitespace, so you can allocation a new buffer of the right size, then take a second pass appending non-whitespace chars, or "IIT", into the new buffer.  Don't forget your null terminator.

Comment: This can easily be done in place, as long as the string buffer has enough space allocated for the new extra characters.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to replacing a single character in a string with multiple characters without using a second string is to process the string from end to beginning.

First, go through the string once, counting how many characters there are to be replaced.  Then compute how many extra characters your replacement will add.  Make sure the string has enough space allocated to handle the new characters.  Then starting with the last character in the string, move each character to the new end of the string, replacing specific characters with your replacement characters.

Example, replace `x` with `zz`

```
xcfdxdfxg---
```

(dashes are space allocated for the string, but not currently used, and of course there should be a `\0` at the end of the string, which also properly gets moved)

```
xcfdxdfxg---
xcfdxdfx---g
xcfdxdf--zzg
xcfdxd--fzzg
xcfdx--dfzzg
xcfd-zzdfzzg
xcf-dzzdfzzg
xc-fdzzdfzzg
x-cfdzzdfzzg
zzcfdzzdfzzg
```

Answer (score 0):

C [String manipulation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/String_manipulation) Standard Library APIs are not that strong to simply replace a Strings. So, You can use lexical analyzer utilities like [Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) which give a REGEX power to find and [manipulate](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_9.html#SEC9) your texts.

> Here is a program which compresses multiple blanks and tabs down to a   single blank, and throws away whitespace found at the end of a line:

```
%%
[ \t]+        putchar( ' ' );
[ \t]+$       /* ignore this token */
```

Flex will generate a C program for you, which do all the work.

**Tutorial:** http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~lgao/teaching/flex.html

[image: Flex]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot since you said that you want to replace the whitespaces with "IIT". Here "IIT" has 3 bytes and the whitespace is a single byte. So how can you store it. You can do this by allocating more memory before placing the string "IIT" . See [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) for more information on this.